# ProGuard can't find classes flyway

Tags: flyway, android-proguard

I use Flyway in the android app.
Now with ProGuard, version 5.3.3 it can't find some referenced classes.

My app build.gradle is

> android {
>
> ```
> compileSdkVersion 26
> buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
> ...
>
> implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.0.7'
> implementation 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
> ```
>
> }

and Proguard output is

> Warning: 
>   core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner$1:
>   can't find superclass or interface
>
> org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFileFilter Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.spring.SpringJdbcMigration: can't find
>   referenced class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLCopyStatement:
>   can't find referenced class org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLCopyStatement:
>   can't find referenced class org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection
>   Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLCopyStatement:
>   can't find referenced class org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLCopyStatement:
>   can't find referenced class org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLCopyStatement:
>   can't find referenced class org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.spring.SpringJdbcMigrationExecutor:
>   can't find referenced class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
>   Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.spring.SpringJdbcMigrationExecutor:
>   can't find referenced class
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource
>   Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.spring.SpringJdbcMigrationExecutor:
>   can't find referenced class
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource
>   Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.spring.SpringJdbcMigrationExecutor:
>   can't find referenced class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
>   Warning: org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't
>   find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't find
>   referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't find
>   referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't find
>   referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't find
>   referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't find
>   referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't find
>   referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't find
>   referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog: can't find
>   referenced class org.slf4j.Logger Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogCreator: can't
>   find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogCreator: can't
>   find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleContext Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.BundleContext Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.OsgiClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.osgi.framework.Bundle Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VFS Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VFS Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner$1:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFileFilter Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner$1:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner$1:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner$1:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile Warning:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner$1:
>   can't find referenced class org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile
>    Note: org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv2UrlResolver:
>   can't find dynamically referenced class org.jboss.virtual.VFS Note:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv2UrlResolver:
>   can't find dynamically referenced class org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils
>   Note:
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.jboss.JBossVFSv2UrlResolver:
>   can't find dynamically referenced class org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project build successfully without classes listed in the question. I just add follow lines in to the proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn org.flywaydb.core.internal.**
-dontwarn org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.spring.**
```